# Debugging aspects with intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm experimenting with AspectJ and finding that intellij doen't seem to step into the `@Around` aspect. For example:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Test{}

@Aspect
public class TestAspect {
    @Around("execution(@aspects.Test * *(..))")
    public void around(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("start1");

        point.proceed();

        System.out.println("end");
    }
}

@Data
public class Library {
    @Test
    public void forceError() {
        System.out.println("running");
    }

    private String foo;
}
```

And while I can compile and see my comments run in a unit test, I can't debug the aspect.

I've tried both aspect annotation based, and using the aspectJ .aj files with intellij to try and get the `Around` aspect to debug.

Comment: Annotate your annotation with the appropriate `@Retention` (ex, `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`)

Comment: I actually do have that on my local, intellij doesn't seem to care.

Comment: Your example works for me with Spring AOP. Can you post a complete example, with how you use a `Library` instance?

Comment: https://github.com/devshorts/aspejcts_test

Comment: SpringAOP isn't the same thing, from what I understand. That's going to use the spring factory and use proxy based "aspects" which is not the same as bytecode weaving.  I don't want to use spring since my downstream projects aren't using spring, so its not going to work well for me

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue.
 
My aspectj app works if I run the main class with gradle script(run task of application plugin, namely gradle clean build run -x test), but if I debugging the app by right-clicking Debug 'MyApp.main()' of the context menu of intellij idea, then the aop will not work.
And I find the solution: Setting ->Build,Execution,Deployment ->Build Tools ->Gradle ->Runner -> tick the option **Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle**, then try to debug by right-clicking the Debug option of context menu of intellij idea and check the result.
This solution only works for gradle, and I have not tried it with maven.

Comment: It doesn't work for maven with pure AspectJ, without Spring AOP